# For what base $A$ is $24_A + 17_A = 40_A$ correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given:

$$24_A + 17_A = 40_A$$

How can I find the base of the following number $A$ so the operations are correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hint to get you started: By definition, in base b, the first digit from the right is representative of the $b^0$ place, the second from the right is $b^1$'s, just like in base 10 the number 12 is $2 * 10^0 + 1* 10^1$

Answer (score 1):

By definition of number base, we know that $24_A=2A+4$, $17_A=1A+7$, and $40_A=4A+0$, the last three terms are all in base 10. Equating them, we get $2A+4+A+7=4A$, and solving for $A$ results in $\boxed{A=11}$.

Checking by adding in base $11$, we see that $27_{11}+17_{11}=40_{11}$, because $4+7=10$ in base $11$, and carry over the $1$, $1+2+1=4$.